# How to set node to left and below in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following tikz code in which I want to set a node to the left and below of an endpoint of a line.

```
\tikzstyle{node} = [font=\footnotesize]
\def\r{0.5pt}
\filldraw[densely dotted] (6.5,0) circle (\r) node[below,left] {$\alpha(t_0+0)$} -- (6.5,2.35);
```

But it only displays on the left. Also, the footnotesize is not set correctly. But in another code like:

```
\filldraw (0,0) circle (\r) node[below] {$c$} -- (10, 0) circle (\r)
```

The footnotesize is set correctly. What is the problem?

Comment: `below left` is an option that sets `anchor = north east`

Comment: `below` sets `anchor = north`;  `left` sets `anchor = east`. They will override each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your added a comma (`below, left`) instead of (`below left`). Adding comma makes the later argument to override the previous ones.

Please, always provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example). You used a command (`\r`) which I may suppose is the radius of a circle, but it is not displayed/defined in your snippet of code. I replaced it for the number `1`.

Also notice I removed the `filldraw` since the text was cover by the color. Adding a length (`below left=20pt`) is a simple way to control the distance between label and node.

A MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{node} = [font=\footnotesize]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[densely dotted] (6.5,0) circle (1) node[below left] {$\alpha(t_0+0)$} -- (6.5,2.35);
  
  \draw (0,0) circle (1) node[below left] {$c_1$} -- (3, 0) circle (1) node[above right] {$c_2$};
  
  \filldraw[densely dotted, red] (10.5,0) circle (1) node[below left=20pt] {$\alpha(t_0+0)$} -- (6.5,2.35);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, \r is a constant. I modified the code.